# the diffrence between api.add_resource(User, '/user/<int:user_id>') and <string:user_id> and <user_id> in flask restful?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have `app.py`:

```
from resources.user import User
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from db import db

db.init_app(app)

api.add_resource(User, '/user/<int:user_id>')
```

and in `resources/user.py`

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from models.user import UserModel

class User(Resource):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, user_id: int):
        user = UserModel.find_by_id(user_id)
        if not user:
            return {"message": 'User not found'}, 404
        return user.json()
```

and in `models/user`

```
from db import db


class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'username': self.username
        }

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, _id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=_id).first()
```

and in `db.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

### My problem:

When I send a get request to `127.0.0.1:5000/user/1` I get a json response and everything is good with the status code 200.

When I send a get request to `127.0.0.1:5000/user/10000078373` I get a json response that 'User not found' and everything is good with the status code 404 that I expect because user `10000078373` does not exist.

However, When I send a get request to `127.0.0.1:5000/user/sdffsdf` I **DO NOT** get a json response; I get an HTML response:

```
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try
    again.</p>
```

I expect an HTML response because I need a restful api that returns **json not HTML**.

If I make a change

`api.add_resource(User, '/user/<int:user_id>')`

to

`api.add_resource(User, '/user/<string:user_id>')`

I would have no problem and would get a json response on `127.0.0.1:5000/user/1` and `127.0.0.1:5000/user/184848484843848` and `127.0.0.1:5000/user/kfkfkjgkg`

### My Question:

My question is, what is the role of <int: ... or <string: ... in this code as I see no difference in the result?

I understand that their role is giving type. My question is what is the point of giving the type. I see no use case in which it might be helpful. The other question I have is how to receive 404 in JSON fromat instead of an HTML form and how to override the default of this error.

Answer (score 2):

The role of `<int:user_id>` and `<string:user_id>` is you are giving type to the passing variable and the variable only accept the type that you given. If you just type `".../<user_id>"` the default type will be string.

In your code, When you assign `<int:user_id>` and you passed integers its perfectly worked. When you passed a string to your Int type variable the compiler not recognized and you get HTML error. Then you changed your type to string (`<string:user_id>`) the compiler recognized and you get response from compiler.

Comment: I edited and added an explanation to the original question.